# Aurelia - Usar/Importar arquivos .js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia pessoal, essa pode ser uma pergunta bem idiota, mas eu sinceramente não estou conseguindo achar absolutamente nada na internet.

Gostaria de saber como incluo meus arquivos .js em um projeto utilizando aurelia, a situação é a seguinte:

Eu tenho um template criado aqui, que contém vários e vários arquivos .JS (vide anexo), esse template usa desde gráficos até tabelas que dependem de arquivos .JS, ao adicionar os arquivos do template na pasta src do projeto, os arquivos .css rodam muito bem, fica lindo, o problema é quando vai utilizar algum recurso que dependa de .JS dá pau.

Segue em anexo uma parte dos scripts que eu estou tentando utilizar.

Mas para ser simples, gostaria de saber, como utilizar um simples arquivo .JS, existe algum procedimento para importar um .JS para o template? Eu tenho que converter o arquivo para algum tipo de outro arquivo que não seja .JS?

Por mais idiota que pareça a pergunta, eu simplesmente não consigo achar nada na documentação e fóruns da internet.[image: Alguns dos plugins .JS/Jquery que estou tentando utilizar.]

Comment: eu não sei nada de inglês mas traduzi no google algo que encontrei parecido com seu problema "Calling external javascript from within Aurelia templates" http://www.sobell.net/calling-external-javascript-from-within-aurelia-templates/

Comment: O caminho normal para incluir uma biblioteca no Aurélia é composto por duas etapas: 1) Importar a biblioteca via npm install <pacote> --save; 2) Ajustar o arquivo aurelia.json que fica na pasta aurelia_project. 
Depois disto, os pacotes ficam disponíveis para serem importados nos demais módulos de sua aplicação. Note que alguns pacotes são "queixo duro", e requerem algumas customizações no aurelia.json.